# c++ including cpp files

Tags: c++, include

when I work on my IDE (visual studio or xCode) I never include cpp files (only h files)  and everything compiles perfectly.

however, when I compile on the cmd/terminal (mostly on my raspberry pi) if I don't include the cpp files the compiler throws many errors because he didn't read the cpp files.

why is that? how does the ide knows to include the currect cpp files? and is there a way to find out if you are compiling through an ide or terminal?

something like:

```
#ifdef IDE_KEYWORD
#endif
```

Comment: Need WAY more information. How are you compiling in the terminal? What compiler, what commands are you running, etc.

Comment: Maybe you did not add the `c++` source files to your project / Makefile...

Comment: Just to make it clear (because the existing answers don't mention this): you **should not** use `#include` to compile several files. IDEs don't do that either. There are other ways to manage your source files, `#include` is not for that.

Comment: IDE's invoke their build system to compile a project/solution. Visual Studio uses *MSBuild* that takes your *.sln file as input (I don't know the details for XCode). If it fails on the command line for you it is because **you** aren't using the build system. Consult your IDEs' user manual to find out, how to build on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The IDE will typically compile each source file (what you are describing as a "cpp file") separately, to produce an object file for each, and then link all the object files (and other libraries).   Mechanically, the IDE does that by invoking the compiler separately for each source file listed in the "project file" and then linking.

When compiling from the command line, it is necessary to specify EVERY source file on the command line - the IDE isn't helping with that, so you need to do it manually.

One option is to compile every source file separately (specify each on a separate command line) and then another command to link all the object files together to produce the executable.   In effect, this (more or less) imitates what an IDE does.

A second option is to list EVERY source file on a single command line - which will cause the compiler to compile each one sequentially and then (depending on what command line options you specify) link the object files together.

Answer (score 0):

IDEs track what files are in the project/workspace and what ones are not. For instance, Visual Studio has a block in the vcxproj file which stores all the compilation units as such

```
<ClCompile Include="yourFile.cpp" />
```

having an ifdef to determine if you are using an IDE should be just a matter of adding `IDE_KEYWORD` to your preprocessor definitions inside your IDE. then if you compile outside of that IDE, the `IDE_KEYWORD` wont be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Visual Studio you can

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
// your code
#endif
```

If not I suppose there is no way.

The error may occur because you are not compiling all the .cpp files and/or are linking not all object files.
If using g++ `g++ -c file.cpp -o file.o` for every file to compile them. Then `g++ file1.o file2.o fileN.o -o finalExecutable.exe` for linking.

If this seems complicated look into Makefiles. They are awesome!